# sed: replace a block of text

Tags: bash, unix, replace, sed, awk

I have a bunch of files, starting with a block of code and I'm trying to replace with another.

Replace:

```
<?php
$r = session_start();
(more lines)
```

With:

```
<?php
header("Location: index.php");
(more lines of code)
```

So im trying to match the block with `sed 's/<?php\n$r = session_start();/<?php\nheader...` but it doesn't work.

I would appreciate help in what is happening here and how to achieve this. I'm thinking in doing this with python instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any extra information you can add? By the looks of things you only want to change the second line in each of your files. Is that correct?

Comment: Is more than the second line, it's a block of code, an old code I would like to replace (about 4 or 6 lines at the start of every file)

Comment: This is not working for me.

I'm trying to get block of text replaced by other and can't do it with this sed example you provided.

This is what I would like to do, match block of text and replace it with another. In this example I would like to replace block of text that is:
"line 2

original text
line 1
line 2
line 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1i\
This is a\
new block of\
code
1,/$r = session_start();/d' file
```

Or if you prefer to place the new code in a file:

```
sed -i '1r replacement_code_file
1,/$r = session_start();/d' file
```

All on one line:

```
sed -i -e '1r replacement_code_file' -e '1,/$r = session_start();/d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `sed`:

```
cat block.txt <(sed '1,/$r = session_start();/d' file.txt) > newfile.txt
```

Simply add the block of text you'd like to add to each file to `block.txt`. The `sed` component simply deletes lines, between the first line and a matching pattern.

Answer (score 0):

sed, tweaked your solution a little bit:

```
sed  '/<?php/{N;s/\n$r = session_start();/\nheader(\"Location: index.php\");/}' file
```